# Powershell script that gets executed on list of VMs of an azure subscription

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a script **VARIASUIT_CHECK_WINDOWS.ps1** that runs on a VM return a result like this:

> "Server Name","GPO_HARMOR","BIOMEDIC_AGENT","EDWARD_STATUS","SENSOR_STATUS","SENTINEL_STATUS"
> "TEST-AZ-VM","OK","OK","OK","OK","OK"

I would like to write a script that gets all the VMs of a specific subscription and runs the script on each VM then write these values on doc file.

I tried firstly to invoke the script from another script to add a loop for all VMs within the subscription, but I didn't work.

Can you help me on this?
Thanks.

```
$vmId = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/TESTRG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/TEST-AZ-VM"

  # Run the "VARIASUIT_CHECK_WINDOWS.ps1" file on the Virtual Machine using the Azure CLI
  $scriptResult = az vm run-command invoke `
        --command-id RunPowerShellScript `
        --ids $vmId `
        --scripts VARIASUIT_CHECK_WINDOWS.ps1

Write-Host $scriptResult
```

Comment: Hi @woodyboow please include the script of .ps1 file

Comment: https://codeshare.io/yog3l0

Answer (score 2):

when I run the ps1 script it returns same output to write a script that gets all the VMs of a specific subscription and runs the script on each VM then write these values on doc file you can make use of below script :

```
# Connect to your Azure account
Connect-AzAccount

# Set the subscription context (replace 'your_subscription_id' with your actual subscription ID)
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId '1234565XXXXXX'

# Get all the VMs in the subscription
$vms = Get-AzVM

# Define the path to the VARIASUIT_CHECK_WINDOWS.ps1 script
$scriptPath = "C:\Users\imrxxxx\xxDrive - Mxxxxx\Desktop\test\VARIASUIT_CHECK_WINDOWS.ps1"

# Loop through each VM and run the script if it's a Windows VM
foreach ($vm in $vms) {
    $vmId = $vm.Id
    $outputFile = "C:\Users\imrXXXX\Drive - MiXXXX\Desktop\test\$($vm.Name)_output.txt"

    # Check if the VM is running a Windows OS
    if ($vm.StorageProfile.OSDisk.OSType -eq "Windows") {
        # Run the VARIASUIT_CHECK_WINDOWS.ps1 script on the VM
        $scriptResult = Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -VMName $vm.Name -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath $scriptPath

        # Save the script output to a text file
        $scriptResult | Out-File $outputFile

        Write-Host "Script output for $($vm.Name) saved to: $outputFile"
    } else {
        Write-Host "Skipping $($vm.Name) as it is not running a Windows OS."
    }
}

# Export the results to a CSV file
$csvFile = "C:\Users\v-imrXXXX\OneDrive - MXXXX\Desktop\test\khan.csv"
$results = @()
foreach ($vm in $vms) {
    $outputFile = "C:\Users\imrXXXX\OneDrive - Microsoft\Desktop\test\$($vm.Name)_output.txt"
    if (Test-Path $outputFile) {
        $content = Get-Content $outputFile
        $lines = $content -split '\r?\n'
        $properties = @{}
        foreach ($line in $lines) {
            if ($line -match '^(.*?):\s*(.*)$') {
                $name = $matches[1]
                $value = $matches[2]
                $properties[$name] = $value
            }
        }
        $properties['Server Name'] = $vm.Name
        $results += New-Object PSObject -Property $properties
    }
}
$results | Export-Csv -Path $csvFile -NoTypeInformation

Write-Host "Results exported to: $csvFile"
```

***Output***:

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/BWYGbIm.png)]

In my subscription I have 2 virtual machines When I run this script, I am able to get all the VMs of a specific subscription in csv file. Then run the `VARIASUIT_CHECK_WINDOWS.ps1` script on each VM in a specific resource group and creates doc file to store the results.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello Imran I updated the script now for each VM I get this as output https://codeshare.io/K8AlwP

I would like to get the value of line 7 and put it in a variable
"RSIEAZ-NHSAPP1P","KO","KO","KO","KO","KO" 
knowing that it can change lines depending on each VM.

Thanks